# Stripe payout error when try to get payout using Node.js

Tags: node.js, axios, stripe-payments

When I try to get stripe pay out to my local bank account using Node.js it shows

`"Payout error: StripeInvalidRequestError: No such external account: '83135907'" error`

I used below code to get payout

```
    try {
      const bankDetails = await getBankDetails(recipientUserId);
      console.log(bankDetails)
  
      if (!bankDetails) {
        throw new Error("Bank details not found for the recipient user");
      }
  
      const payout = await stripe.payouts.create({
        amount: amount,
        currency: "usd",
        method: "instant",
        destination: bankDetails.Account_No,
      });
  
      console.log("Payout successful:", payout);
      return payout;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Payout error:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

when i try to execute this  console logs

Payout error: StripeInvalidRequestError: No such external account: '83135997'
at StripeError.generate (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Fastmove\FastMove-Backend\node_modules\stripe\cjs\Error.js:10:20)
at res.toJSON.then.Error_js_1.StripeAPIError.message (C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\Fastmove\FastMove-Backend\node_modules\stripe\cjs\RequestSender.js:105:54)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
type: 'StripeInvalidRequestError',
raw: {
code: 'resource_missing',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
message: "No such external account: '83135997'",
param: 'destination',
request_log_url: 'https://dashboard.stripe.com/logs/req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd?t=1689500737',
type: 'invalid_request_error',
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Sun, 16 Jul 2023 09:45:37 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',
'content-length': '335',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials':
'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',

'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'fc292080-c66b-4c47-bc91-32052790e6c1',
'original-request': 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd',
'request-id': 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',

'x-stripe-routing-context-priority-tier': 'livemode',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
statusCode: 400,
requestId: 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd'

},
rawType: 'invalid_request_error',

code: 'resource_missing',
doc_url: 'https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing',
param: 'destination',
detail: undefined,
headers: {
server: 'nginx',
date: 'Sun, 16 Jul 2023 09:45:37 GMT',
'content-type': 'application/json',

'content-length': '335',
connection: 'keep-alive',
'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
'access-control-allow-methods': 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS, DELETE',
'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
'access-control-expose-headers': 'Request-Id, Stripe-Manage-Version, X-Stripe-External-Auth-Required, X-Stripe-Privileged-Session-Required',
'access-control-max-age': '300',
'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store',
'idempotency-key': 'fc292080-c66b-4c47-bc91-32052790e6c1',
'original-request': 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd',
'request-id': 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd',
'stripe-version': '2022-11-15',
'x-stripe-routing-context-priority-tier': 'livemode',
'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload'
},
requestId: 'req_LLA2AlTPZpULOd',
statusCode: 400,
charge: undefined,
decline_code: undefined,
payment_intent: undefined,
payment_method: undefined,
payment_method_type: undefined,
setup_intent: undefined,
source: undefined
}

how to fix this

Comment: Seems the destination is invalid. Looking at the docs and other examples, this should look something like `ba_xxxx....` but yours is just a number. Maybe you provided the bank's account number instead of stripe's account id?

Comment: Yes I provide bank account number because I want to get pay out to bank account. Is there any method to do that

Comment: Well, you probably have to register that account with stripe first. And then use the Id of that account in your payout. How do you think stripe would know which bank the account number 8313... belongs to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.